# Prevent XMLSerializer from escaping special chars in script tags

Tags: javascript, dom, serialization

I am trying to make a script that will generate an html page embedding scripts. I build the document in memory then serialize it with XMLSerializer.serializeToString. Problem: script tags don't receive a special treatment and "a = 5 < 3" becomes "a = 5 < 3;" which triggers an error when I open the generated html (a JavaScript error saying Lt doesn't exist).

I tried to add a CDATA section manually (with createTextNode but with the code of the CDATA in it) but it doesn't work (the serializer ignores it and escape characters). I tried to use the built-in method to create a CDATA section (createCDATASection or something like that) but I get an error saying this isn't supported for html documents.

How to tell the serializer not to escape special characters for script tags ? It's fine to do it for other tags but this one (and style too) is special.

I think it's a trivial problem but I have been stuck on it for hours.

I think I am missing something.
I would REALLY like to avoid using a third party library.

Thanks in advance.